# Difference between "column is null" and "column = null" in where clause in db2?

Tags: sql, db2

I am getting different results when I run the query with above clause but not able to understand why. can any one explain what is the difference between the two clauses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result of `column = null` is unknown (null), since it can't be known what `null` really is. If you want to test for null and get a boolean value back you need to use `is null`. So, `` `column` is null `` is the correct syntax to use.

Comment: it means, I will always get 0 rows if the condition is column = null

Comment: @GuruKulki, that is right. Because the database engine can't determine that `column = null` ever, so if you make that a condition for selecting a row it can't select anything. Whereas the engine can determine if `column IS NULL` so it can return the rows where that condition is true.

Answer (score 5):

A comparison to null always evaluates to false, so `column = null` evaluates to false as well as `column != null`, independently of the value of column. If you want to actually check whether a value is null, you have to use `column is null`.